# downloading multiple files(bytes) to dir in python using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to use requests to download free audios from a list of urls that I am reading from a txt file.
The issue is that I am not sure how to write multiple audio (.mp3) to a desired dir.
in the code sample below I would end up with an error, stating that I have selected a directory.
How can I change this code so that the audios all save to a selected dir.
as a bonus it would be nice to be able to name the audios being downloaded in an automated fashion.

I am new to programming, so I hope my lack of knowledge here doesn't bother you. apologies in advance:

```
with open('text.txt') , 'r') as rf:
    with open(os.path.join('/path-to-dir-where-i-want-to-write'),'wb') as wf:
        content = rf.readlines()
        for line in content:
             str1 = ('https://examplewebsite' + line) #generates the full url for the mp3 file
             audio = requests.get(str1)
             wf.write(audio.content)
```

Comment: You want to move the second `open()` command inside the `for` loop - after all, you want to write a new file for each file downloaded, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import os

if not os.path.exists('/path-to-dir-where-i-want-to-write'):
    os.makedirs('/path-to-dir-where-i-want-to-write')

with open('text.txt') , 'r') as rf:
  content = rf.readlines()
  for line in content:
    file_where_i_want_to_save = line
    with open(os.path.join('/path-to-dir-where-i-want-to-write', file_where_i_want_to_save),'wb') as wf:
      str1 = ('https://examplewebsite' + line) #generates the full url for the mp3 file
      audio = requests.get(str1)
      wf.write(audio.content)
```

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately, it just states that the dir or file (line in this case) doesn't exist

Comment: ok. updated code above. Python can't create file if their directory is not exists, but it should create a new file if it is not exists by default